# Setting up Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I been working on a small project at work on my work machine, came home to try it out on my laptop and when I create a new rails app. This is the error I receive.

```
Installing i18n (0.7.0) 
Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occured while installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot   continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
Jose-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:~ josegomez$ bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile
Jose-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:~ josegomez$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14 revision 34678) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

So I tried to update to 1.9.3

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551
```

after the update I did a quick check and got this error

```
`Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/josegomez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-   1.9.3-p551 --with-opt-dir=/opt/local --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-    install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/josegomez/.rvm/log/1435281659_ruby-  1.9.3-p551/configure.log
GEM_HOME=/Users/josegomez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails3tutorial
PATH=/Users/josegomez/.rvm/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/josegomez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-   p318@rails3tutorial/bin:/Users/josegomez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/bin:/Users/josegomez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin:/Users/josegomez/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/josegomez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails3tutorial:/Users/josegomez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/josegomez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 --with-opt-dir=/opt/local --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in   `/Users/josegomez/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.`
```

When I run: ruby -v I get:

```
ruby(62937,0x7fff7c0c8300) malloc: *** error for object 0x100801a08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a MacBook Pro, I'd go with the following. From the command line:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

once that's done, try:

```
rvm use 2.2.2 --default
gem install bundler
cd /Path/to/your/rails/app
bundle install
```

Please let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks! But when I run bundle install I'm still receiving errors [After running bundle install](http://pastebin.com/fc5gPALE)

Comment: Add I find out I don't have Rails installed so I run it and I get another [error](http://pastebin.com/fwBK2P5P). I'm really completely new to this so I want to make sure I get everything right so I push my app live. I seem to be running into errors a lot.

Comment: Instead of the first command, try this one: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` This will get you everything you need ;)

Comment: Still not working :/ I'm going through line by line to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: I receive this message `libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.`

Comment: Run the following command: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"; brew install libxml2`. Then try installing Rails again :)

Comment: You're going to love this. I have Homebrew already installed, as I followed another tutorial but when I run `brew install libxml2` I get this error `Warning: libxml2-2.9.2 already installed`. I'm thinking about uninstalling everything and reinstalling from scratch. Which I'm looking up how to haha

Comment: If it helps any I removed RVM. I'm going to reinstall everything from scratch. I hear rbenv is suggested any thoughts? `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)` Here is a list of gems installed on my machine currently.

Comment: RVM is fine, I have it on 2 Macs and 1 Ubuntu server and it never gives me problems. What's the error message you're currently receiving when trying to install Ruby & Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste these command if you are using ubuntu

```
1- sudo apt-get update
2- sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
3- sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
4- \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
5- source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
6- rvm install 2.2.2
7- rvm use 2.2.2 --default
8- ruby -v
9- echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
10- gem install bundler
11- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
12- sudo apt-get update
12- sudo apt-get install nodejs
14- sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
15- rails new myapp -d mysql
```